# Convergence of Infinite series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is just a "fact" given to me in my problem, but I'd like to understand why...

Suppose $|f(x)|=1, \forall x$, why can't the following limit exist?

$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(kt)t$

I suppose it's super trivial but I'm not sure if my reasoning is right. Is it because the $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}$ comes after the infinite sum, so that the sum has already blown up before t got a chance to "counteract"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. If your define $a_k=f(kt)t$ then $|a_k|=|t|\not\to 0$ when $k\to\infty$, so the series can't converge.

In fact, you are taking limit to a function (of $t$) that it's not well defined or, in the best of scenarios, may be $\pm\infty$ for $t\ne 0$.